# Ubuntu 16.0.4.1 brightness only working after sleep

Tags: nvidia, suspend, laptop, brightness

I have tried several of the fixes on here for brightness on my **Asus G55VW** laptop an **NVidia 660m**.  The brightness and fn keys to control brightness are both working now.  The only problem I have now is whenever I first boot, the brightness does not work.  It will only work after I put the laptop to sleep, then bring it back out.  Once I do that, everything works perfectly.  I'm not sure what I'm missing on boot that is causing this *not to* work, and I'm not sure what coming out of sleep is doing to cause this *to* work.

Comment: Try this thread- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160152. The solution is at the bottom, you need to create an xorg file.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change how the system identifies itself to the BIOS. Fortunately, this is pretty simple:

1. In a terminal, run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Find the line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.
3. Before the second quote, add `acpi_osi= acpi_osi= acpi_backlight=native pcie_aspm=force`. It should look like this when you're done:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi= acpi_backlight=native pcie_aspm=force"
   ```
4. Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot. Your brightness buttons should work natively.

This is (likely) a bug with on both Asus' and Linux's end, where the two won't talk to each other normally. Therefore, if you tell Linux to identify itself in a different way than normal, The Asus BIOS will do things in such a way that Linux can understand and expect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't work for systems >13.01.

Comment: @PatrickNegus This works on my 16.04 system, so I'm not quite sure what you mean...

Comment: Sure. I didn't downvote your solution, however, just to let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I've tried both of the solutions above and got a little closer with the acpi_backlight=native added, but still a little weird how it's working.  I'll keep at this, any other ideas or experience with this laptop I'd be glad to listen.